# how to remove repeat url string after url

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to remove everything that comes after the ? created in the url by this as I need it to open sites on my local network that do not work with that string after it

```
       <script> function changeForm(e, formRef)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = document.getElementById('myName').value;
        var port = document.getElementById('port').value
    formRef.action = formRef.getAttribute('data-url') + encodeURIComponent(name) + ":" + 

encodeURIComponent(port);
        // Send
        formRef.submit();
    } 
</script>




<form data-url="http://" action="" onsubmit="changeForm(event, this)" autocomplete="off">
    <center>

    <input type="text"  name="w" style="width: 40%;"
    maxlength="255" id="myName" placeholder="url" required/>




<input type="text"  name="w"
maxlength="255" id="port" style="width: 15%" placeholder="port" />
<br>
<center><input type="submit" value="Local Search!" /></center>
</form>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far and why specifically didn't it work for you?

Comment: Where is the "url" in your code and also share a sample value of what your current url looks like which you want to update and remove stuff after `?`

Comment: You could find the [index of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) '?' and take the [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) of everything before it. You could also [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) it on '?' and take the first element.